I am getting an error: SyntaxError: missing: after property id 1: at line 2
var oList = {
  "NO EXCEPTIONS TAKEN:" - 1,
  "MAKE CORRECTIONS NOTED:" - 1,
  "REVISE AND          RESUBMIT:" - 1,
  "REJECTED:" - 1
};
var dlg = initialize: {
    function(dialog)
  } {
    dialog.load({
      lst1: oList
    });
  },
  commit: function(dialog)
} {
  this.oSelect = dialog.store().lst1;
}, description: {
  name: “Review Action”,
  elements: [{
    type: “view”,
    elements: [{
        type: “static_text”,
        item_id: “stat”,
        name: “Select an Item”
      },
      {
        type: “popup”,
        item_id: “lst1”,
        char_width: 6
      },
      {
        type: “ok”
      }
    ]
  }]
}
`
    };

This is for an Adobe stamp to have the user choose a response that is added to the stamp. I've tried various ways to notate the var dlg = initialize: {function(dialog)} but nothing is working.  I suspect I have other formatting errors as well.

What are you expecting var dlg = initialize: {function(dialog)} to mean?

If you're trying to create an object where the key is initialize, you need {} around it, just like in your oList variable.

function(dialog) is also not valid, it should be something like function(dialog) { some code here; }

In the first line, the : goes outside of the "

I think your time might be better served taking some tutorials in the basics of JavaScript syntax; how to create objects, functions, etc., rather than having others painstakingly go through your code pointing out all of the errors.

You have misplaced curly braces in your function expressions. The syntax of a function expression is
function(parameters) {
    body
}

The corrected statement is:
var dlg = {
  initialize: function(dialog) {
    dialog.load({
      lst1: oList
    });
  },
  commit: function(dialog) {
    this.oSelect = dialog.store().lst1;
  },
  description: {
    name: "Review Action",
    elements: [{
      type: "view",
      elements: [{
        type: "static_text",
        item_id: "stat",
        name: "Select an Item"
      }, {
        type: "popup",
        item_id: "lst1",
        char_width: 6
      }, {
        type: "ok"
      }]
    }]
  }
};

